# What does "extra dedicated" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Something dedicated is a thing that was given to a chosen person, what is '[extra dedicated](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ACYBGNTjh2K5NW65hb5g1PRiPuz2uzF3CA%3A1570456746428&ei=qkSbXaHfGeeAjLsP2_qKgAU&q=extradedicated&oq=extradedicated&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i7i30l4j0i7i10i30j0i8i7i30l4.6724.6724..6897...0.2..0.87.87.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.Kr78p0zdS1M&ved=0ahUKEwih3IWkp4rlAhVnAGMBHVu9AlAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)'. I ask this because i couldn't find any reference that explains 'extra' up to now.

Comment: It depends on the context.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. Do you mean that it seems a as if there is an intensifier modifying an absolute adjective?

Comment: @Lawrence I can't imagine any context wherein it could fit in, Cascabel I'm specially searching whether if is a difference

Comment: @tungsten Welcome to EL&U. As a reminder, Stack Exchange questions should demonstrate your initial research efforts; if looking up the definitions of *dedicated* in a dictionary does not answer your question, please [edit] it to include a link and an explanation why.

Comment: Gosh, what could it possibly mean?

Comment: If you cannot imagine _any_ context where it would fit, then why would you need it?

Comment: Some plausible contexts: "That guy is extra dedicated; he goes to the gym twice a day." "There was extra (that was) dedicated last week." What context did you have in mind when you asked the question?

Comment: I don’t understand the confusion here. There is hot sauce and *extra* hot sauce. There is mean and there is *extra* mean. There is dedicated and there is *extra* dedicated. What is the doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are confusing two meanings of **dedicated**

> 1: devoted to a cause, ideal, or purpose
>
> 2: given over to a particular purpose

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dedicated

It seems that in your question, you are using definition 2. In the case of "extra dedicated," dedicated is used as in definition 1.

**Extra** is simply an intensifier.